# Where to find info about file system counters in Mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

While running a mapreduce job I get an output like this:

```
 11/09/15 21:35:16 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 24
 File System Counters
 FILE: Number of bytes read=255967
 FILE: Number of bytes written=397273
 FILE: Number of read operations=0
 FILE: Number of large read operations=0
 FILE: Number of write operations=0
 Map-Reduce Framework
 Map input records=5
 Map output records=5
 Map output bytes=45
 .......
```

Here in the first line it says Counters: 24.
Where can I find more info about these counters.

I am most interested in **large read operations=0**, what are these? 
If anyone have any knowledge or reference about these, please reply.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend you take a look at [Tom White's Hadoop book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449311520), especially Chapter 8.1 where he gives a detailed list of counters and their meanings. You can find an online version [here](https://www.inkling.com/read/hadoop-definitive-guide-tom-white-3rd/chapter-8/counters).

For the **large read operations**, it corresponds to the number of large file system read operations such as list files under a large directory. It was introduced in [HADOOP-6859](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-6859) where it is described as this: on file system, most of the operations are small except listFiles for a large directory. Iterative listFiles was introduced in HDFS to break down a single large operation into smaller steps. This counter is incremented for every iteration of listFiles, when listing files under a large directory.

This ticket also explains some of the other new counters:

- **read operations** - number of read operations such as listStatus, getFileBlockLocations, open etc.
- **write operations** - number of write operations such as create, append, setPermission etc.

I would advise you look at the `FileSystem.Statistics` class which details some additional filesystem counters as described [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.Statistics.html)

Comment: Your answer din't help at all, din't find anything about large read operations. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Did you read my last link? It states: "getLargeReadOps() -> Get the number of large file system read operations such as list files under a large directory". Can't really get more precise than that...

Comment: Get the number of large file system read operations such as list files under a large directory.... I have seen that earlier but I am a little confused about what is a "large directory".

Comment: @HishamMuneer Updated my answer with more details about the large read ops.